# I would like to split multiple URLs from a single Google Sheets cell and then add them as images into a Google Doc

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Sheet doc that has column called Imgs which contains a cell with multiple URLs that links to multiple images:

[image]

So, I would like to do the following with an Apps Script:

1. Split the URLs by eliminating the comma delimitator
2. Find a way to create an array with each URL
3. Pick URL by URL from the array and then attach each one to the Google Doc as images, leaving something like this

   [image]

Here's the link to the Google Sheet as an example: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YosQwoFMbqoljRGdZddoLQgrj-gOYVYtOtm424bdSwk/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a view only link to your sheet

Comment: @JohnA your answer provided before has been useful, but is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to separate the URLs and then attach them to a Docs through tags (or something else) as images (such as jpeg, png, etc). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: GAS is available in doc as well, so you will need to give some thought on how to interface sheets and docs. GAS is based on javascript and there is a split method for strings that works like the SPLIT() function in sheets. Perhaps you can do everything in docs using google app script.

Comment: @JohnA sorry for the delay in responding, here's the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YosQwoFMbqoljRGdZddoLQgrj-gOYVYtOtm424bdSwk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Without your specific sheet I made a similar one

[image]

E9 has a long string of URLs

'https://www.agustafamily.net/Hayden.png,https://www.agustafamily.net/wedding.jpg

Using the SPLIT function returns individual URLS

```
=SPLIT(E9,",")
```

The using the IMAGE() function to get the images

```
=image(E10)
```